# How do I get the bounds of a layerGroup in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have added multiple geoJSON layers to my map by first adding them to a LayerGroup and then adding the layerGroup to the map.

Now I want to call fitBounds on the map with the  combined bounds of all the layers, the problem is that layerGroup does not have the method getBounds

what can I do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a `L.FeatureGroup` instead of a `L.LayerGroup`, as the former does implement [`L.FeatureGroup.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#featuregroup-getbounds).

Comment: Thanks, I did that. I should have gone for it from the start. featureGroup makes LayerGroup unnecessary in my opinion.